# Error con context android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy intentando crear una vista con un list view (Típica app de agenda de contactos)

Cuando lanzo la aplicación me sale el siguiente error:

> 2020-04-19 21:36:00.250 8223-8223/es.ubu.lsi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: es.ubu.lsi, PID: 8223
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.ubu.lsi/es.ubu.lsi.ContactsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
>           at es.ubu.lsi.ContactsActivity.onCreate(ContactsActivity.java:35)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Entiendo que le estoy pasando un contexto nulo, pero no se por qué es así.

He supuesto esto por la línea del error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference at es.ubu.lsi.ContactsActivity.onCreate(ContactsActivity.java:35) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127) at

**Mi código:**

```
package es.ubu.lsi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import es.ubu.lsi.modelo.Contacto;

public class ContactsActivity extends Activity {
    private static String TAG = CallsActivity.class.getCanonicalName();
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_CONTACTS = 15;
    private Contacto[] datos = new es.ubu.lsi.modelo.Contacto[NUMBER_OF_CONTACTS];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contactos);

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CONTACTS; i++) {
            datos[i] = new Contacto(Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i));
            Log.v(TAG, datos[i].toString());
        }

        ContactsActivity.AdaptadorContactos adaptador = new ContactsActivity.AdaptadorContactos(this);
        ListView listOpciones = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewContactos);
        listOpciones.setAdapter(adaptador);

        // Set listener...
        listOpciones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Click on: " + datos[arg2].getNombre(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.show();

            }
        });

    }


    private class AdaptadorContactos extends ArrayAdapter {

        /**
         * Context
         */
        Activity context;

        /**
         * Constructor.
         *
         * @param context context
         */
        AdaptadorContactos(Activity context) {
            super(context, R.layout.contactos, datos);
            this.context = context;
        }

        /**
         * Load the views with current data.
         *
         * @param position    position
         * @param convertView view
         * @param parent      parent
         */
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View item = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (item == null) { // first time
                LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactos, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.nombre = (TextView) item
                        .findViewById(R.id.lblNombre);
                holder.apellidos = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.lblApellidos);

                item.setTag(holder); // load the view holder in the item's tag
            } else { // view previously loaded
                holder = (ViewHolder) item.getTag();
            }

            holder.nombre.setText(datos[position].getNombre().toString());
            holder.apellidos.setText(datos[position].getApellidos().toString());

            return (item);
        }
    }
    /**
     * View holder.
     *
     * @author rmartico
     */
    class ViewHolder {
        TextView nombre;
        TextView apellidos;
    }
}
```

EDITO:

Añado el layout: contactos.xml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es un problema con el contexto, el problema indica que no puedes llamar el mètodo `setAdapter()` ya que la instancia del `ListView` tiene valor null.

Si no estas encontrando la referencia del `ListView` la razòn es que el layout `contactos.xml` que cargas  mediante `setContentView()` no contiene un listView con id `listViewContactos`.

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contactos);
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ListView listOpciones = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewContactos);
        listOpciones.setAdapter(adaptador);
```